# Left join is not working on web server

Tags: php, mysql, join

Below sql query is working in localhost, when im trying it in web server its not working.

```
SELECT  t1.student_id,t1.id AS id1,t2.id AS id2,t3.id AS id3,t1.costperhour AS cs1,t2.costperhour AS cs2,t3.costperhour AS cs3,t1.sub_hours AS th1,t2.sub_hours AS th2,t3.sub_hours AS th3,MIN(t1.subjectass_id) AS sub1,MIN(t2.subjectass_id) AS sub2,MIN(t3.subjectass_id) AS sub3    FROM    tb_adhocdetails t1
        LEFT JOIN tb_adhocdetails T2 
            ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id 
            AND t2.subjectass_id > t1.subjectass_id
        LEFT JOIN tb_adhocdetails T3 
            ON t2.student_id = t3.student_id
            AND t3.subjectass_id > t2.subjectass_id
        LEFT JOIN tb_adhocdetails T4 
            ON t3.student_id= t4.student_id
            AND t4.subjectass_id > t3.subjectass_id
WHERE t1.student_id=360
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean in practice? it would be nice if you could provide an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) about your problem, so we could actually see your table structure and db data.

Comment: Keep in mind that the problem could be configuration settings on the web server, or domain authentication on the separate machine, or security settings on the login, etc.  Without any more context than a dump of a SQL statement and "it's not working" on a second machine, there's nothing really to go on.

Answer (score 0):

On some Linux MySQL Servers, the table/column names are case-sensitive. As you are declaring the tables with uppercase "T" and using them with lowercase "t", you might have errors for unrecognized table